# Вывод значения массива через цикл

Tags: javascript

```
let mass = {
    "a": {
        c1: "aaaa",
        c2: "bbbb",
        c7: "ffff"
    },

    "b": {
        c1: "ccc",
        c2: "dddd",
        c10: "tttt"
    },

    "c": {
        c1: "ffff",
        c2: "kkkk",
        c3: "mmmm"
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как мне вывести все эл-мы c1 и c2 в консоль?
я могу вывести какой то конкретный эл, к примеру прописав console.log(mass.a.c1).
а как это задать в цикле можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let mass = {
    "a": {
        c1: "aaaa",
        c2: "bbbb",
        c7: "ffff"
    },
    "b": {
        c1: "ccc",
        c2: "dddd",
        c10: "tttt"
    },
    "c": {
        c1: "ffff",
        c2: "kkkk",
        c3: "mmmm"
    }
};

for(let k in mass)
  console.log(mass[k].c1);
```